# What api can I use to connect to IPSec or L2TP Programatically Android

Tags: java, android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I need to connect to an api programatically in my app,but can't seem to find a way. I see VpnService, but this seems to only give you access to the TUN. How do I go about connecting to my already build IPSec and L2TP servers that have a username and password on it: something that VPNService doesn't have an option for.

Comment: hey @Bk Razor did you found any way